# Syntax error on express.js after migrating to node v14, changing files to type mjs and import statements

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to update my old server to the newer standards by removing require and including import. However the code that I had within the previous files included destructuring of the req.body, which worked fine before. Now I get the error that there is a syntax error. Any ideas?

Quoted error

```
/controllers/addStemDatabase.mjs:10
  } = req.body;
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:145:18)
```

Place where it is used

```
export const handleAddStemDatabase = (req, res, db) => {
  const {
    last_modified_email,
    name,
    project_hash,
    filetype,
    locked,
    downloadable,
    private
  } = req.body;

};
```

Package Json has this

```
  "type": "module",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.16.1"
  },
```

Import statement

```
import { addStemDatabase } from "./controllers/addStemDatabase.mjs";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`private` is a reserved word in JS/ECMAScript ([reference](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/reserved-keywords)). I suspect that your previous version of node wasn't yet based on a version of EMCAScript that considered that word private but that it is now.

Update: After doing some testing I found that `private` seems to only be considered a reserved word in modules, i.e., `.mjs` files. Perhaps you previously had this code in a `.js` file instead?

You'll probably need to rename your variable.

```js
  const {
    last_modified_email,
    name,
    project_hash,
    filetype,
    locked,
    downloadable
  } = req.body;
  const private_field = req.body.private;
```

Comment: Although you are probably right that this would throw an error, since I have had to fix this error on other outdated code, this is unfortunately not the cause of the issue.

I had another file with the same issue without reserved words in the de-structuring. By removing the de-structuring line and changing the following variables to req.body.X meant that this issue jumped to another file. Unfortunately, it would be a lot to remove all the de-structuring and seems to me counter intuitive.

Comment: Are you sure? I've tested the code I showed you with and without the `private` variable, and the destructor worked just fine when I removed that variable.

Comment: When the destructor didn't work with private for you, did you get the error:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word"
Or
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'"

Because, as I wrote above - I didnt get the reserved word error and I had the same syntax error in other mjs files that didn't use reserved words in the destructor.

Comment: I never got an error talking about a reserved word, I only got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}`. But hey, if you really don't want to even try this solution, you don't have to. But it works.

Comment: As I said multiple times, I don't just have this error on the variable "private".
I have it on all the different variables that are deconstructed in similar files on the server.
All were solved by doing the same thing, instead of deconstructing, writing directly req.body.(object key). I am looking for a solution to be able to keep deconstructions within all files. If you would prefer, I can update the question to be one of the other examples, that were not reserved words. 

I appreciate the attempt at helping though, thanks!

Comment: Yes, please. Once I can reproduce the error (like I was with `private`), I might be able to help. node 14 definitely supports the destructor.

Comment: I must humbly accept that I was wrong, I do apologize Christian.
Not only were there two occurrences of reserved words, but it seems that I had the aforementioned syntax errors before changing the package JSON file to "module".

Either way, you have been a great help thank you!